# Python 3.6 is required. Current python version is ''2.7.15rcl"

Tags: python, functions, azure

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. after connecting to docker using sudo docker login
I'm trying to use azure functions on Ubuntu by creating a new function app using **func init MyFunctionProj --docker** and have the following error:
Python 3.6 is required. Current python version is '2.7.15rcl'
I've installed azure functions tools using: 
**sudo apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools**
Any idea why it fails?

Comment: What does `python3 --version` say? For the failing part we need error messages to help out!

Comment: python -V shows : Python 3.6.7

Comment: python3 --version shows : Python 3.6.7

Comment: when running **func init MyFunctionProj --docker** I have always the same problem "Python 3.6 is required. Current python version is ''2.7.15rcl"

Comment: Please check your docker setup and make sure it sees the path to the python3 installation in Ubuntu. Point your azure function to it if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

An Ubuntu package that depends on another package can have this dependancy specified, so if you install it, the dependancy comes also. With python there is for several years a transition ongoing from 2.7 to 3.x because there are some incompatible differences, so an application does not automatically run also on python3. You can install multiple versions of python simultaniously, but than you have to be explit about which version to run or from which path you run it. The default version can be printed like this `python -V`. In my Ubuntu 18.04 I have also a python2.7 and python3 in my path.

If you don't have python3 you can install it with apt ...

`apt install python3-minimal`

Comment: I installed python3-minimal but the problem still persist, by running python -V, I've Python 3.6.7 but I always having the same problem